# How to search a bool field in Doctrine by its equivalent string values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a database table with a `tinyInt` column col `(0=no, 1=yes)`. I need to be able to do a `LIKE` search of the text-equivalent values in that column based on text entered by the user. For example, a user searching for "n" should give `MySQL` query of `"col LIKE '%n%'"` and return a count of all rows with `col=0`.

I am using `Doctrine 2` in `Symfony 4`. I tried the query builder and `createQuery()`, and both give me the same error.

Is what I'm trying possible? (I don't know if there is any other way to do it.)

Sample `createQuery()` code:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em ->createQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(1) AS c FROM App\Entity\MyEntity t 
    WHERE (CASE WHEN (t.bool_field=1) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) LIKE '%n%'"
    );
$res = $query->getResult();
```

The result is an error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 111: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=,
>   !=, got 'LIKE'

Any help would very much be appreciated.

Comment: searching for `"n"`  needs to be searching for `"no"`

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Elanochecer Users see page with a datatable (datatables.net) with "no" and "yes" in the column. The datatable will have several text-field colums, this yes/no field, and a search field will show above it. If a user types something in the search field ("yes", "no", "n", etc.), I would like to search any of the fields in the datatable, including the tinyint field. The search has to be done on the server-side.

Comment: I feel like that's a bad approach, turning a number into a string so you can query it with `LIKE` ... I mean ... what if the app gets translated, should it turn into "ja" and "nein" or "oui" and "non"? I wouldn't even expect rows with "no" in a boolean field to get selected, when I type "n", because it's just ... unexpected and most likely useless. because I probably want to find rows where the text has some "n" in it, and you force rows with no "n" onto the user, because some boolean field is "0" or "false"

Comment: I think you are complicating it too much. You can just show the user a select with yes and no as that's all that can be found with 1 and and 0 as values and send that on the request.

Comment: @Jakumi - Perhaps it's true that this is not the best approach. The reason I looked at it is that I will have other text fields in the datatable, and other enums like this yes/no field. I was hoping to have just a single search field to cover them all, and not add filter dropdown fields. (And yes, the idea is to internationalize the app, and then the search would be for no/yes in English, non/oui in French, etc.) But maybe this can't be done in Doctrine. (It works fine in plain mysql, although I am not sure of its performance.)

Comment: @Elanochecer - yeah, maybe it is too complicated - see my reasons for it in my comment above. I was hoping there was some way to do it, but of course there is a tradeoff. If too complicated, then I will stick with a simple filter.

Comment: @AlivetoDie That's one way of doing it, but then, for "yes", I would have to handle "y", "e", "s", "ye", "es", "yes", and that's too complex than I want to go. Is this what you meant?

Comment: You could add a function that checks whether the search term, `'n'` in your example, is present in either a 'no' or 'yes' string. Then if it is present in either of those, you will know whether to search the column for `1` or `0`. This way you can also add more 'no' or 'yes' strings for internationalization later on.

Comment: @Teun Thanks, I ended up doing it this way. If you can add your suggestion as an answer, I will make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function that checks whether the search term, 'n' in your example, is present in either a 'no' or 'yes' string. Then if it is present in either of those, you will know whether to search the column for 1 or 0. This way you can also add more 'no' or 'yes' strings for internationalization later on.